# Python: instantiating new instance of class from list of classes

Tags: python

Disclaimer: This may be a terribly simple question but I'm attempting to learn Python.

Essentially, I have a list of classes and given a random number, I'd like to construct a new instance of the class indexed at that random number.

```
  #The members of the list below are class objects  
  SHAPES = [I_shape, J_shape, L_shape, O_shape, S_shape, T_shape, Z_shape]
```

I've discovered how to do it given a string so I guess I could just use the name attribute of the class but I'm curious if there isn't an easier way to go about this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Tetris, I presume? Making a separate class for each shape is really not what you want, tbh; have one class with different data in the instances to describe the shape (a 4x4 grid of booleans suffices). The fundamental behaviour of each shape is the same, really.

Comment: Karl, good guess.  Thanks for your comment and looking at the code some more, I believe that I agree with you on behavior.  However, if you can abstract the boolean matrix specific to each type of shape via a child class, shouldn't you do that since the instantiator of said class doesn't really need to understand the mechanics of each shape and how they are structured graphically?  I'm trying to think of a good reason to do it as your propose...

Comment: Here's the reason to do it as I propose: there **are no** "mechanics of each shape". Rotating a shape works the same way no matter what the shape is: common code is used to transform the 4x4 grid. Similarly for collision detection etc. The "graphical structure" is data. You don't need a separate integer subclass for each integral value, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your `SHAPES` array, you can simply call the class object:

```
new_obj = random.choice(SHAPES)()
```

The `random.choice(SHAPES)` picks one of your `I_shape`, `J_shape`, etc, and the final `()` calls the constructor for that class object, just as if you had written `I_shape()` or whatever.

Comment: `SHAPES` isn't actually an array though :P

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
obj = SHAPES[your_random_number]()
```